# How do I select multiple Tax Rates - BY TEXT SEARCH in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, jquery, tax-rule, tax-rates

I am struggling with selecting Tax Rates in Magento 2.4.4.

There was a fantastic answer to this issue: [How to select multiple tax-rate In Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/255757/how-to-select-multiple-tax-rate-in-magento-2)

Where the Console code lets us select ALL tax rates listed. However, I need to select only 20,000 of 40,000 tax rates. And I'd really like to not do that manually. **Is anyone able to edit this code to allow a text search?**

I was trying (without any luck) all sorts of versions of something like:

```
require(["jquery"],function($){
$( ".mselect-fixed label" ).each(function( index ) {
  if($(this).children("input").hasClass("mselect-checked")){}
  else if($(this).children("span").includes("WI")){$(this).trigger('click');
    }});
});
```

[image: tax rates selected in Magento 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested on 2.4.3-p1.

The following code selects the first 2 rates. Replace 2 with 20000 and it should work.

```
require(["jquery"],function($){
  $( ".mselect-list-item label" ).each(function(index) { 
    if(index < 2)
       if(!$(this).children("input").hasClass("mselect-checked")){this.click()}
  });
});
```